# Reutilização de função na mesma página com Jquery (iniciante) evento Change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual a possibilidade de reutilizar $.change ?

Pessoal tenho um problema. 
Preciso em uma mesma página usar

vários changes em várias selects.
Funciona assim:
Primeiro change:
Usuário escolhe no select 1

O change roda e um get json busca via Json na URL e mostra o resultado.

Segundo change :
Usuário escolhe no select 2 (que é diferente do select 1)
O change roda e m get json busca via Json na segunda URL e mostra o resultado.

O problema é:

Quando rodo cada change em páginas separadas Roda perfeito.

Mas quando rodo na mesma página não funciona.
O que preciso fazer para que todos os changes (terei mais de 2) rodem na mesma página.

Uso dessa forma peguei da documentação do Jquery >

```js
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $(this).val() + " ";
    });
    console.log(str);
   
    var url = "http://minhaurl.com/json?cidade="+str;
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
Json rodando perfeito.
 });


  
})
  .change();
```

**Apenas repito a função mudando os parametros URL, STR, e o select.**

Existem outras maneiras de conseguir o mesmo efeito do change. 
E que eu posso repetir na mesma página ?

OBS: Cada select **tem seu ID**. Cada seletor que recebe os valores **tem seu ID**.

Obrigado, abraços

OBS 2: Não pretendo juntar elas, 
Elas são separadas.

Cada um tem sua URL, e tem suas respostas.

Para ajudar [http://pastebin.com/LVQa4HAU][1]

Sou bastante iniciante. 
Então não sei muito.

Comment: Você quer juntar todos os valores de todos os `selects` selecionados no mesmo **str** e passar para a URL?

Answer (score 2):

Aconselho atribuir um `id` para cada select... Assim você pode identificá-los sem problemas.

```
//Select 1...
<select id="selectTimes">
    <option>Flamengo</option>
    <option>Vasco</option>
    <option>Palmeiras</option>
</select>

//Select 2...
<select id="selectEstado">
    <option>RJ</option>
    <option>SP</option>
    <option>MG</option>
</select>
```

Depois disso é só atribuir um `.change()` para cada elemento:

```
$( "#selectTimes" ).change(function () {
    //botei seu exemplo só para contextualizar..
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $(this).val() + " ";
    });
    console.log(str);

    var url = "http://minhaurl.com/json?cidade="+str;
    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
        //Json rodando perfeito.
    });
});

$( "#selectEstado" ).change(function () {
    //TODO
});
```

Comment: Esqueci de por no post. 
Cada select tem seu ID. 

cada seletor que recebe os valores tem seu ID.

Comment: então basta atribuir à cada  `id` um evento `.change()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Dá para melhorar o seu código completamente, mas seria necessario analisar qual a finalidade do arquivo final.

A resposta mais rápida neste caso seria especificar uma `class` para cada `select` em seu `HTML`, e depois no seu `JS`, atribuir o que cada classe deverá requisitar ao seu servidor.

Da forma que você está fazendo está muito generalizado. Você está dizendo para que o JS faça a request do JSON em todos os elementos `select` da página. Sendo assim, todos eles terão o mesmo comportamento.

Comment: Sou bastante iniciante. 
Então não posso reclamar de nada.

Answer (score 0):

Resposta dada por uma pessoa no facebook.

Dyemerson Almeida

[> no pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dHSv27pM)

Achei essa resposta tbm 
substitui str2= $(this).val(); 
Por

str2= $("#iddoselect").val();